# I want a pandas script to line up values from one excel sheet to another based on the values in the first spreadsheet

Tags: python, pandas, merge

this question seems vague and similar questions have been asked before but Im still confused! any help will be much appreciated. I dont have a very good programing background so my wording is not great I hope you understand:

I have two excel spread sheets with 10s of thousands of data points. The first (Sheet A) has addresses eg:

```
   house_number        street      suburb
0            43  Smith Street   Frewville
1            45  Smith Street   Frewville
2            47  Smith Street   Frewville
3            49  Smith Street   Frewville
4            51  Smith Street   Frewville
5            53  Smith Street   Frewville
6             1   Flinders St  Kensington
7             3   Flinders St  Kensington
8             5   Flinders St  Kensington
9             7   Flinders St  Kensington
```

the second (Sheet B) has some of the same streets but with an ID column too eg:

```
          ID  house_number           street      suburb
0    5509            43     Smith Street   Frewville
1    5120            26    Taylor Avenue    Glenside
2    4731            34  Brussels Street   Frewville
3    4342            12  Brussels Street   Frewville
4    3953             1      Roger Court     Clifton
5   12098             4     Elizabeth St     Clifton
6    2024             7      Flinders St  Kensington
7   28388            10        Queens Rd  Kensington
8   36533            13        Queens Rd  Kensington
9    4478           346   Jefcott Street    Glenside
10  52823            19   Jefcott Street    Glenside
```

I want a pandas script that adds a column to sheet A with the ID from sheet B if the addresses are in both excel sheets

trying to remove NaN?

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_excel('sheeta.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('sheetb.xlsx')

sheet1 = df1.join(
(df1.reset_index()  # make a column of pandas index so join can work
     .merge(df2, on=["house_number","street","suburb"], how="inner") # find fullmatches
     .set_index("index") # make index same as original sheeta
     .loc[:,["ID"]] # only want ID column to go back into join
     .astype("Int64") # force the types that support int NaN
     .dropna(sheet1)
))
print(sheet1)
```

Comment: everything is about approach not coding ability.  Typically there will be data quality issues,  how do you deal with those.  What do you consider a match?  Simplest being a full text match,  if other matches are allowed how define two addresses are the same.   Provide 10 rows from each sheet that you want help with. (`df.to_dict(orient="list")` so it's easy to paste into an IDE)

Comment: Thanks for your help despite the lack of info, Does this help?

Comment: There are a few errors. sometimes there is 'st' instead of 'street' etc. also some have the wrong suburb. the full text match is probably all I can handle at the moment! haha Thanks again for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commented for explanation of approach.  Have found two addresses where ID from *sheet2* comes back onto *sheet1*

```
import io
sheeta = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""   house_number        street      suburb
0            43  Smith Street   Frewville
1            45  Smith Street   Frewville
2            47  Smith Street   Frewville
3            49  Smith Street   Frewville
4            51  Smith Street   Frewville
5            53  Smith Street   Frewville
6             1   Flinders St  Kensington
7             3   Flinders St  Kensington
8             5   Flinders St  Kensington
9             7   Flinders St  Kensington"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")
sheetb = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""ID  house_number           street      suburb
0    5509            43     Smith Street   Frewville
1    5120            26    Taylor Avenue    Glenside
2    4731            34  Brussels Street   Frewville
3    4342            12  Brussels Street   Frewville
4    3953             1      Roger Court     Clifton
5   12098             4     Elizabeth St     Clifton
6    2024             7      Flinders St  Kensington
7   28388            10        Queens Rd  Kensington
8   36533            13        Queens Rd  Kensington
9    4478           346   Jefcott Street    Glenside
10  52823            19   Jefcott Street    Glenside"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

sheet1 = sheeta.join(
(sheeta.reset_index()  # make a column of pandas index so join can work
     .merge(sheetb, on=["house_number","street","suburb"], how="inner") # find fullmatches
     .set_index("index") # make index same as original sheeta
     .loc[:,["ID"]] # only want ID column to go back into join
     .astype("Int64") # force the types that support int NaN
))

print(sheet1.to_string())
```

**output**

```
   house_number        street      suburb    ID
0            43  Smith Street   Frewville  5509
1            45  Smith Street   Frewville  <NA>
2            47  Smith Street   Frewville  <NA>
3            49  Smith Street   Frewville  <NA>
4            51  Smith Street   Frewville  <NA>
5            53  Smith Street   Frewville  <NA>
6             1   Flinders St  Kensington  <NA>
7             3   Flinders St  Kensington  <NA>
8             5   Flinders St  Kensington  <NA>
9             7   Flinders St  Kensington  2024
```

Comment: Thats great! do I need to make changes to the script if I have other columns on excel that I do not need to match? also can I delete the rows with NaN's?

Comment: If you only want rows that match,  there is more work going on that needed here - the `merge()` is doing all the work and only returns two rows....  also you can choose the use `dropna()` later to remove.  I think more columns won't mess it up - as code chooses only one column "ID" to go back